# Don't show answered color if the question qualifies as unanswered

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, unanswered-questions

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean

When a question has the green answered background, it can be confusing if it still qualifies as unanswered (no upvoted answers). I would like it to show the red text, even if the number would be higher than 0, if there aren't any upvoted answers.

Related: [How to mark an answer as "It doesn't answer the question that was asked?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281710/how-to-mark-an-answer-as-it-doesnt-answer-the-question-that-was-asked)

The gist of the issue raised in the linked question, which is also how i feel:

Some people (such as me) normally skip answered questions (irrespective of whether it's accepted or not), unless the title is intriguing or makes me feel i would learn something out of that discussion. If not all, many a potential answerer for the question might be browsing with same mindset. The bogus answer thus effectively will bring down the attention the question otherwise would have received. This can effectively be solved by treating the downvoted answers (less than zero points) as non-answers and ignoring them when counting the answers (for displaying in main feed or wherever applicable).